# pass arrow function to component prop

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-props

I am trying to pass the result of the handleRedirectUrl() function to the ShortUrlField component as a prop.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, please help me

```
const handleRedirectUrl = () => {
    urlService
      .getShortenedUrl(urls.slice(-1)[0].short_url)
      .then((returnedUrl) => {
        setRedirectedUrl(returnedUrl);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        handleCreateErrors(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        return redirectedUrl;
      });
  };

  //display shortened url
  const shortUrlDisplay = renderShortUrl ? (
    <ShortUrlField
      originalUrlValue={urls.slice(-1)[0].original_url}
      shortUrlValue={urls.slice(-1)[0].short_url}
      redirectedUrlValue={handleRedirectUrl()}
    />
  ) : (
    <EmptyField />
  );
```

The urlService function

```
const getShortenedUrl = (urlToGet) => {
  const request = axios.get(redirectShortenedUrl + `${urlToGet}`);
  return request.then((response) => response.data);
};
```

Edit 1:
I was not returning anything with my **handleRedirectUrl** function. Also, I was not passing it properly to the props. I have changed my code to

```
  const handleRedirectUrl = () => {
  return urlService
    .getShortenedUrl(urls.slice(-1)[0].short_url)
    .then((returnedUrl) => {
      setRedirectedUrl(returnedUrl);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      handleCreateErrors(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      return redirectedUrl;
    });
};
```

```
//display shortened url
const shortUrlDisplay = renderShortUrl ? (
  <ShortUrlField
    originalUrlValue={urls.slice(-1)[0].original_url}
    shortUrlValue={urls.slice(-1)[0].short_url}
    redirectedUrlValue={handleRedirectUrl}
  />
) : (
  <EmptyField />
);
```

It does not work. the **getShortenedUrl** function is never called

Edit 2: Added the **ShortUrlField** component code

```
import React from "react";


const ShortUrlField = (props) => {
return (
  <div>
    <p>
      <a href={props.originalUrlValue}>{props.originalUrlValue}</a> became{" "}
      <a href={props.redirectUrlValue}>{props.shortUrlValue}</a>
    </p>
  </div>
);
};

export default ShortUrlField;
```

**Edit 3: I made it work!!**

Many thanks to **@ZsoltMeszaros** for pointing out the right path to me.

I have passed a state variable to my conditional rendered component, and added an effect hook that basically sets the state if the component is rendered.

Much thanks to all of you that commented.

Comment: You need to pass a reference to the function and call it from the child component. Don't invoke it... Meaning this: `redirectedUrlValue={handleRedirectUrl}` and not this: `redirectedUrlValue={handleRedirectUrl()}`

Comment: Why don't you just pass `redirectedUrl` to the component instead of the function so when it's updated React could re-render them? Just because the promise settled, it doesn't mean `setRedirectedUrl()` already updated `redirectedUrl`. Also, `finally()`'s handler needs to be a function.

Comment: @SakoBu my bad, did not solve it though..

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros redirectedUrl will get changed after a call is made to the handleRedirectUrl function. I need the function call to be made after the ShortUrlField is displayed by the conditional render function

Comment: If you want the function to be called, you could pass down a callback function to `ShortUrlField ` and use `useEffect` to call it on render. How does your `ShortUrlField` component look like?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand where is this **setRedirectURL** function, but anyway your **handleRedirectUrl** function returns nothing

```
const handleRedirectUrl = () => {
  return urlService
    .getShortenedUrl(urls.slice(-1)[0].short_url)
    .then((returnedUrl) => {
      setRedirectedUrl(returnedUrl);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      handleCreateErrors(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      return redirectedUrl;
    });
};
```

May this can work as you can see like your axios request, this is returning result of urlService.

Comment: I was not returning anything indeed. Even so, I have made the changes as instructed by you and by the people commenting above, yet nothing really happens. For some reason, my service function does not get called